# What's the performance of the "address of" operator &?

Tags: c++, performance, addressof

I have to pass a lot of pointers in my code in the midst of a big loop, (so I have lots of expressions like `foo(&x, &y, ...)`). I was wondering whether I should **store the pointers as separate variables** (i.e. cache) for performance (at the cost of introducing more variables and clutter in my code)?

(Doing lots of matrix mult. and the CUBLAS library insists on pointers...)

Comment: The optimizer can answer that question better than you can.

Comment: This is the kind of macro optimization that are not worth thinking about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No -- the address-of operator is about as inexpensive/fast as anything you can hope for. It's *possible* to overload it, and such an overload *could* be slower, but overloading it at all is fairly unusual.

Comment: If the address-of operator had been slow, C wouldn't be what it is now, much less C++.

Comment: + , but why do you says `"overloading it at all is fairly unusual."`?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Well, hopefully, the fact that overloading it is an evil, satanic practice should discourage enough people from doing it so that it becomes unusual. And that seems to be what has happened.  I certainly don't see this done often. Do you?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley :) your are correct because I have no example...Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`std::addressof` incurs no penalty at all. When it boils down to assembly code, we only refer to objects through their addresses anyway so the information is already at hand.

Concerning `operator&`, it depends whether it has been overloaded or not. The original, non-overloaded version behaves exactly like `std::addressof`. However if `operator&` has been overloaded (which is a very bad idea anyway, and quite frowned upon), all bets are off since we can't guess what the overloaded implementation will be.

So the answer to your question is: no need to store the pointers separately, you can just use `std::addressof` or `operator&` whenever you need them, even if you have to repeat it.

Answer (score 1):

in C++ there are references, what you are describing sounds more like a behaviour for the C language rather than C++.

that kind of signature for C++ methods it's usually implemented to avoid copying, by default when you call a method and pass some arguments to it, this arguments generate a local copy, having references it's a technique that help you avoid this overhead for the copy.

Answer (score 1):

It would be very efficient. If you are using Linux, you can check by using objdump. The following is how fooP(&var1, &var2) looks like in the x86 architecture. It is nothing more than a LEA instruction.

```
 fooP(&var1, &var2);
 8048642:       8d 44 24 1c        lea    0x1c(%esp),%eax  -> this is to get the address of var2 to eax
 8048646:       89 44 24 04        mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)   -> this is to save the address to the stack for later fooP call
 804864a:       8d 44 24 18        lea    0x18(%esp),%eax  -> address of var1
 804864e:       89 04 24           mov    %eax,(%esp)
 8048651:       e8 be ff ff ff     call   8048614 <_Z4fooPPiS_>
```

Reference in this case is actually same as the above.